# Ubuntu 20.04 keeps asking for authentication

Tags: 20.04, authentication

[image]

It doesn't matter how many times I give it the password, it keeps randomly popping up again.

Also, I can just cancel, and it will work fine for a (short) while, then pop up again.

How do I make it understand once and for all I am authenticated?

Comment: Your question should include the complete output of `ls -l /bin/env`